# How to align table with borders to baseline grid

Tags: html, css

If I have a `line-height` equal to my baseline grid, row height and text wrapping works out nicely according to the grid. But if I want horizontal dividers, it throws off the baseline. Normally I'd use a negative margin to account for the border's height, but that doesn't have any effect on `display:table-cell` elements.

```
table {
  line-height: 20px;
}
th, td {
  border-bottom: solid 1px black;
}
```

I can't change the line height to `19px` to make up for it because that would mean text wrapping would throw off the grid. Are there other ways to make up for that `1px` additional height on each line?

Answer (score 3):

This can be solved by using `box-shadow` for the between-cell lines instead of actual borders.

```
td, th {
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 black;
}
```

The box shadow won't take up any additional space, so it won't throw lines off the grid.

Here's a [jsfiddle showing it in action](http://jsfiddle.net/theazureshadow/vh899Lrm/).